# How to properly use Golang packages in the standard library or third-party with Goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

Hi Golang programmers,

First of all I apologize if my question is not very clear initially but I'm trying to understand the proper usage pattern when writing Golang code that uses Goroutines when using the standard lib or other libraries.

Let me elaborate: Suppose I import some package that I didn't have a hand in writing that I want to utilize.  Let's say this package does a simple http get request somehow to a website such as Flickr for example.  If I want a concurrent request, I can just prefix the function call with the go keyword.  But how do I know, that this package when doing the request doesn't already do some internal go calls itself therefore making my go calls redundant?

Do Golang packages typically say in the documentation that their method is "greened"? Or perhaps they provide two versions of a method, one that is green and one that is straight synchronous?

In my quest to understand Go idioms and usage patterns I feel like when using even packages in the standard lib that I can't be sure if my go commands are necessary.  I suppose I can profile the calls, or write test code but that feels odd to have to figure out if a func is already "green".

I suppose another possibility is that it's up to me to study the source code of whatever I'm using and understand how it should be used and if the go keyword is necessary.

If anybody can shed some light on this or point me to the right documentation or even a Golang screen-cast I'd much appreciate it.  I think Rob Pike briefly mentions in one talk that a good client api written go is just written in a typical synchronous manner and it's up to the caller of that api to have the choice of making it green or not.

Thanks for your time,

-Ralph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function / method returns some value(s), or have a side effect like that (io.Reader.Read) - then it's necessarily a synchronous thing. Unless documented otherwise, no safety for concurrent use by multiple goroutines should be assumed.

If it accepts a closure (callback) or a channel  or if it returns a channel - then it is often an asynchronous thing. If that's  the case, it's normally either obvious or explicitly documented. Asynchronous stuff like this is usually safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Comment: http.Get in the http package returns *Response, Error values and is synchronous and I don't see in the documentation where it says it is  safe to use it in goroutines but I can by wrapping it an anonymous go func(){} and therefore get the benefit of using this call with a goroutine.  What am I missing?  Here is the package doc on http.get: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get

Comment: Get is a method of http.Client. The docs for the Client type declare it to be safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer but the terminology 'synchronous' and 'asynchronous' is unhelpful here. The important point that is being made is that some API functions are stateful (or part of a state-based sequence) and therefore *should not* be shared between multiple go-routines. The Go strap-line is "do not communicate by sharing memory, instead share memory by communicating". The second paragraph above is confusing: if channels are used, there will be *concurrency* and this is where care is needed. Whether this is synchronous or asynchronous is irrelevant.